# java - Upload file to imageshack.us

Tags: java, android, urlconnection, imageshack

I'm trying to upload image to the "Imageshack.us" , they have [HTTP API](http://api.imageshack.us/#h.bw7qsvxlg22a)  and I am using it to upload my image, but unfortunately I always get this response from server :

> { 
>      "success":false,
>     "process_time":33,
>    "result":{
>
> ```
>   "max_filesize":5242880,
>
>   "space_limit":52428800,
>
>   "space_used":0,
>
>   "space_left":52428800,
>
>   "passed":0,
>
>   "failed":1,
>
>   "total":1,
>
>   "images":[
>
>   ]    },    "error":{
>   "error_code":1,
>   "error_message":"One or more file uploads have failed",
>   "error_info":[
>      "failed_uploads",
>      {
>         "test.PNG":{
>            "error_code":1,
>            "error_message":"Not a valid image file",
>            "error_info":{
>               "Content-Type":"",
>               "filesize":0
>            }
>         }
>      }
>   ]    } }
> ```

Here is my code for rereiving image (I am trying to achieve all this on Android) :

```
public static String storeDrawable(){

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.pctemplate3);

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "test.PNG");
        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return file.getAbsolutePath();

    }
```

and here is actually request to server code :

```
try {
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();

    String param = Settings.getInstance().getUserAuthToken();

    File binaryFile = new File(path);
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just
// generate some unique random value.
String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.
URLConnection connection = new URL("https://api.imageshack.us/v1/images").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset),
            true); // true = autoFlush, important!
    // Send normal param.
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"auth_token\"")
            .append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
    writer.append(CRLF);
    writer.append(param).append(CRLF).flush();
    // Send text file.
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"")
            .append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
    writer.append(CRLF);
    writer.append(API_KEY).append(CRLF).flush();
    // Send binary file.
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append(
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file@\"; filename=\""
            + binaryFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
    writer.append(
        "Content-Type: "
            + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(binaryFile
                    .getName())).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
    writer.append(CRLF).flush();
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(binaryFile);
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush(); // Important! Output cannot be closed. Close of
                        // writer will close output as well.
    } finally {
        try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
    writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end
                                    // of binary boundary.
    // End of multipart/form-data.
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF);

    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
    String line;
    StringBuffer responseStr = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        responseStr.append(line);
        responseStr.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) writer.close();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Maybe someone has experience with Imageshack, or I am doing something wrong in general ? Please HELP ! 
Thanks in advance , Mike.

Comment: can you print your logcat error here

Comment: @Nambi There are no errors in Logcat, only fail response from server that I print in question.